# Using Gesture Transition to show UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

So I am using this Github Package for my application: https://github.com/jakespracher/Snapchat-Swipe-View

And I was wondering something.. When I drag down, it uses a scrollView to change the current view, to some other view. But how can I make something like: On the phone, when you drag down from the status bar, it shows a view on top of the current one, with out replacing it so you can see both the views. How can I create do something like that in my application, when dragging down on a view to make another view come down on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a custom interactive presentation transition. Your new view is a presented view controller's view, and the transition animation is customized and is tied to the user's gesture by way of a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer. When the pan gesture starts, you call `presentViewController`, but you have previously configured this view controller to use a custom animation with a transitioning delegate conforming to UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, and the whole thing takes off from there.